# Dissimilarity matrix of a scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, statistics, scipy

I am searching for a Python implementation of computing dissimilarity measures of a sparse matrix. I used using scipy.spatial.distance.pdist. But I get an error:

```
 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I think this is because pdist does not work on scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix. It works fine on dense matrix. So far I have been using

```
Dismat = A.T*T
```

to compute the euclidean distance, where A is the sparse matrix and Dismat is the dissimilarity matrix. But I would like to compute other distance such as Manhattan, jaccard, shortest path and so on.

I am wondering if anyone know whether there is a python package that calculates dissimilarity measures of a scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix. That would be great!